# Reinstall Ubuntu 14.10 over existing Ubuntu 14.10 installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, 14.10

I have Ubuntu 14.10 installed as the sole OS on Dell Latitude E5540 64 bit system by a 3rd party. The installer admitted he didn't know much about working with Linux OS. When he installed Ubuntu 14.10, he established the boot partition to be very small. This has created problems in that the partition has 0% free space remaining and my system has been unable to install important updates.  I have deleted older files from the boot partition but the problem remains critical and unable to update properly. Further, the system will currently only boot in recovery mode.  I am considering simply reinstalling Ubuntu 14.10 but not sure what the final result will be. Will Ubuntu 14.10 on reinstall delete and over write the current, corrupt, unwanted installation of Ubuntu 14.10 or will it install as a second OS next to the existing installation?  Is there a tutorial available that might provide instructions on reinstalling 14.10 on a system which already has 14.10 installed on it?  Are there alternative solutions which might be available to increase boot partition space and update the current OS to a healthy status?  Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is download 64 bit [Ubuntu 14.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/) - choose the `ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso` file.

Burn it onto an empty disk. Choose the option to install the distro over the present one and it'll do exactly that for you.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you directed him to the wrong .iso

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you either install 14.04 LTS (Long term support) or 15.04. It is quite simple to install over the previous installation, just select "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" in the graphical install.

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded to 15.04. The problem I'm experiencing now is that when I open a terminal and run "sudo apt-get update" for example the terminal asks for my password won't accept any information in response to the request. The white rectangle simply blinks as if my keyboard doesn't exist. I'm not sure what to do to correct this. Any ideas on a possible solution?  Thanks!

Comment: Enter your password, it won't show what you type for security purposes.